# Median using mobile window bash script

Tags: linux, bash, windows-mobile, median

i need to create a file txt that contains a list of Median value that change
if i have a file like:

1. **1**
2. **2**
3. **35**
4. **40**
5. **50**

i want an output like

1. **1**
2. **1.5**
3. **2**
4. **18.5**
5. **35**

i tried picking up one number at the time from my input file then using sort but i didn't go far..
i hope i made myself clear, thank you!

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use awk to realize this. For example when you have your data in a file named `in.txt`:

```
 awk '{c[NR]=$1; asort(c); if (NR%2) {print c[(NR+1)/2]} else {print (c[(NR/2)]+c[(NR/2)+1]) / 2.0}}' < in.txt
```

results in the output

```
1
1.5
2
18.5
35
```

Comment: If they are in order you don't need to asort.

Comment: Reduced code `awk '{c[NR]=$1;print NR%2?c[(NR+1)/2]:((c[NR/2]+c[NR/2+1])/2)}'`

Comment: my data isn't sorted so i used awk '{c[NR]=$1; asort(c); if (NR%2) {print c[(NR+1)/2]} else {print (c[(NR/2)]+c[(NR/2)+1]) / 2.0}}' Input > Output but it prints "awk: line 2: function sort never defined"